# Prevent Writer from splitting line in a footnote

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

Create a new document, type "see the footnote", insert a footnote, and in the footnote text type the following:

```
This is a footnote . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

Then add a second space after the word "footnote". You will see that the word "footnote" has moved to the next line. Why it happens and how to prevent it? Probably there is some setting, but I cannot find it.

[image]

The second image with formatting marks:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To prevent wrapping at that spot, use [non-breaking spaces](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/ug/text/shared/guide/space_hyphen.html). This will force wrapping to occur after "is". To keep all the words together, change the other spaces as well.

```
This is a  footnote . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

You can see that these are not normal spaces by selecting the space and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to show [U+00a0](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm).